# Is it True that Vivekananda admitted in a letter to Ms. Christina Greenstidel to sacrificing a goat?

Tags: history, animals, vivekananda, kali, sacrifice

The letter at issue was written by **Swami Vivekananda** to Ms. Christina Greenstidel on Nov. 12, 1901, and it contained these words:

> 'Day before yesterday, however, came the ***Puja of Kali***. We had an image too, and ***sacrificed a goat*** and burned a lot of fireworks. ...'

Is it True that Vivekananda admitted in a letter to Ms. Christina Greenstidel to sacrificing a goat?

Comment: Can you please link the source for your letter's claim?

Comment: @Vivikta http://www.vivekananda.net/KnownLetters/1901.html   Check the following date:12/11/1901 ,Sister Christine.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is simply “*Did**Swami Vivekanand do it”?

[This website mentions this](http://www.vivekananda.net/KnownLetters/1901.html)

So in short,apparently,**Yes**.

If you ask me “why did Swamiji do it”?I don’t know.
But animal sacrifice to mother Kali is mentioned in Bhagavatam(so I have heard).So I don’t think it is scripturally invalid.